# audio/webm Google with Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I've changed from `audio/wav` to `audio/webm` due to browse portability and sound quality and since then, I could not find any way to make google transcript the sound.

`audio/wav` works perfectly using `encoding: 'LINEAR16'`, no `sampleRateHertz` needed.

After change to `audio/wav`, transcription failed with `Invalid recognition 'config': bad sample rate hertz message.`

So I have tried all frequencies allowed `[8000,16000,24000,48000]` times all formats allowed `['FLAC', 'LINEAR16','MULAW','AMR','AMR_WB','OGG_OPUS','SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE']` and the transcription results were always empty.

I am using `node.js` as server.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Are you experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Yeah very similar, actually I'm trying to transcribe webm and m4a audio files to text but I get empty response like this: results { }

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve it?

Comment: Yes, Google now can handle it.